# Restricting Generic Type to Float but need some operations

Tags: rust, traits

So I have written a *very* simple DFT algorithm in rust. I have been trying to make it more extensible by letting the function be generic but restrict the generic to only accept floating point types. It was a bit of a battle but I was able to get this far where I am making use of the `num-traits`, `ndarray` and `num-complex` crates.

```
use ndarray::{prelude::*};
use num_complex::{Complex, Complex64};
use num_traits::float::Float;
use num_traits::cast::FromPrimitive;

pub fn dft<T>(x: Array1<T>) -> Array1<Complex<T>>
where 
    T: Float + FromPrimitive,
{

    let N = x.len();
    let twopi: T = T::from_f32(std::f32::consts::PI * 2.0).unwrap();
    let mut out = Array1::<Complex<T>>::zeros(N); // preallocate memory
    for k in 0..N {
        let mut sum: Complex<T> = Complex::<T>::new(T::from_f32(0.0).unwrap(), T::from_f32(0.0).unwrap());
        for n in 0..N {
            let phase: Complex<T> = Complex::<T>::new(T::from_f32(0.0).unwrap(), 
                -(twopi * T::from_usize(n).unwrap() * T::from_usize(k).unwrap()) / T::from_usize(N).unwrap());
            let arg: Complex<T> = Complex::<T>::new(x[n], T::from_f32(0.0).unwrap()) * phase.exp();
            sum += arg;
        }
        out[k] = sum;
    }
    return out;
}
```

The error I am getting from the compiler is when I use the addition assignment operator (last line of outer for loop). The compiler is complaining that the generic needs further restricting to ensure the use of that operator. Specifically it is saying:

```
error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `Complex<T>`
  --> src\ft.rs:41:13
   |
41 |             sum += arg;
   |             ---^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             cannot use `+=` on type `Complex<T>`
   |
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
29 |     T: Float + FromPrimitive + std::ops::AddAssign,
   |                              +++++++++++++++++++++
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
29 |     T: Float + FromPrimitive + std::ops::SubAssign,
   |                              +++++++++++++++++++++
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
29 |     T: Float + FromPrimitive + std::ops::MulAssign,
   |                              +++++++++++++++++++++
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
29 |     T: Float + FromPrimitive + std::ops::DivAssign,
   |                              +++++++++++++++++++++
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
29 |     T: Float + FromPrimitive + std::ops::RemAssign,
   |                              +++++++++++++++++++++
```

My question is as follows, how should I go about solving this ? Should I simply further restrict the generic to ensure this or is there another restriction I could apply that will cover all of these cases. I am fairly new to the making a generic function and restricting using traits so its quite possible that there is an easier way to go about this that I haven't thought of.

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Your issue, as the compiler points out, is the `sum += arg;` line.

The `+=` requires that the type implements `std::ops::AddAssign` to do the in-place addition. However, `Float` does not require that the type implements it (none of its required traits include it).

Since `Float` requires `Copy` and `Add` though, you can just write it long-form: `sum = sum + arg`.

Comment: That makes sense but I don't understand why the compiler wants to restrict the generic for all <Operation>Assign traits just because I have used the AddAssign op